# shortcut key for diffing a file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

What is the **shortcut key for diffing a sourcefile** in VSCode?

- Seems like I can only do diffs from the `Git View`
- On top of that I seem to only have the ability to right-click and `Open Change`, so no seemingly obvious shortcut key from there as well.

Ideally what I would like to do is have the diffing ability on the explorer view or from the git view via shortcut key?

Answer (score 0):

With the update to 0.3.0 there is now a command to diff the opened file to another file. You can assign a keybinding to it, the command id is `workbench.files.action.compareFileWith`

Answer (score -2):

There is a special tool for diffing, not sure it answers your question though.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d8d61cc9-6660-41af-b8d0-0f8403b4b39c

Comment: I think that this is only for Visual Studio 2013? I am also using git and this seems to be for TFS only?

Comment: The question is for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @BenjaminPasero you can diff more than just VS code.